# Nested UIScrollView does not paint

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch

I am building an application which allows the user to view and edit data on a daily basis.  To accomplish this i have created a view in Interface builder which contains all of the daily data, and i "tile" this view within an appropriately sized UIScrollView to allow the user to swipe between the days.  The view contains two UITextFields, a couple UILabels, and a UITextView.  At any given time i have five instances of this view which i re-position around and update the data for the appropriate position.

Everything works great with the exception of the UITextView.  The UITextView does not display its Text property until the user has interacted with it (I'm guessing this triggers a redraw).

Is there an easy way to get the UITextView to "paint" its content when its not on screen (but still added as a subview to another view)?

Answer (score 0):

One thing you can try, which is what I just did to fix the same problem, is hook into the parent scrollview's scrollViewDidScroll delegate function. Then in that function, send a message to the UITextView that would force a redraw, my method was setting its frame to the same frame. It's pretty brute force but it's better than nothing.